# How to take clickable 360 degree tour to explore the area

Tags: photos

I know how to take 360 view photos on android like [this one](https://www.google.co.in/maps/uv?hl=en&pb=!1s0x3bacc0797b9aa92d%3A0xf93adc4c5b61f370!2m20!8m2!1m1!1e2!16m16!1b1!2m2!1m1!1e1!2m2!1m1!1e3!2m2!1m1!1e6!2m2!1m1!1e4!2m2!1m1!1e5!3m1!7e115!4shttps%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FSri_Ramana_Ashram!5sramana%20ashram%20-%20Google%20Search&imagekey=!1e10!2sAF1QipO9_gDw8RldN_a7Ms9OxYOmJo-IDVlUYS1h5KMe&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi18caMyLTcAhVKpo8KHd6TCRcQoioI7wEwFw&activetab=panorama).

But I am not getting how can take 360 pictures which will allow me to click on various location in that picture and after clicking on any location, it opens up another 360 picture, something like [this](https://www.google.co.in/maps/uv?hl=en&pb=!1s0x3bacc0797b9aa92d%3A0xf93adc4c5b61f370!2m20!8m2!1m1!1e2!16m16!1b1!2m2!1m1!1e1!2m2!1m1!1e3!2m2!1m1!1e6!2m2!1m1!1e4!2m2!1m1!1e5!3m1!7e115!4shttps%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FSri_Ramana_Ashram!5sramana%20ashram%20-%20Google%20Search&imagekey=!1e10!2sAF1QipO8--R_OOl6R9eqsQj7He-bpXO8rVbvaJq25KN9&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi18caMyLTcAhVKpo8KHd6TCRcQoioI7wEwFw&activetab=panorama).

Note that first one is simple 360 picture which you can rotate spherically, but you cannot click anywhere in that picture to open new 360 picture taken at that location. While you can do this in second picture.

I am able capture 360 degree photo like the first one. But, how do I capture pictures like second one on Android? Is there any official googleapp?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a feature of Google Maps/Street View which has some guidelines for that effect:

From [Publish and connect 360 photos with the Street View app](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/7011737?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop):

**Step 2: Connect your photos**

Your photos may be automatically connected within 24 hours if:

- You’ve made and published a set of 360 photos according to these [spacing recommendations](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/7012050#tips_multiple_photos).
- "Geotag 360 photos" is turned on.
- You've earned and activated the trusted badge in the Street View app.
- You’ve used auto-capture to make indoor 360 photos within two small steps of each other (1 m / 3 ft).
- You’ve used auto-capture to make outdoor 360 photos within five steps of each other (3 m / 10 ft).

*You can also have the Street View app suggest the five closest 360 photos that you can connect.*

- Open a published photo.
  In the top right, tap More [the three dots]  and then Connect nearby photos.

**OR**

**Connect Photos Yourself**

1. Open the Street View app.
2. On the "Profile" tab, find a photo and tap Select.
3. Pick the photos you want:

   - Choose two photos: Tap the ones that you want to connect.
   - Choose all photos: In the top right, tap More [three dots] and then Select all.
4. In the top right, tap More [three dots] and then Connect 360 photos.
5. Your photos will show up on the map as numbered markers.
6. Tap and drag each photo to the correct location. Swipe left and right on the photo to see all directions.
7. To try your new connection, open your photo in the "Profile" tab and tap the white arrow.

Comment: can I do this myself in browser?

Comment: @Mahesha999 Programming questions is considered off-topic here. Related: https://developers.google.com/vr/discover/360-degree-media

Comment: its not programming question, I was asking if there is any website on which I can perform same steps as you stated in your answer for Street View app